# Wicket: override browserinfopage

Tags: wicket

I'm enabling Wicket to gather the browser information:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setGatherExtendedBrowserInfo(true);
```

Therefore I'm seeing a BrowserInfoPage with some standard message. I want to prevent users from seeing this message.

I'm trying to override BrowserInfoPage and want to leave it blank, as it shown here: http://markmail.org/message/fqbunzoddmh3dplx

I'm getting the following error.

> Unexpected RuntimeException Last cause: The component(s) below failed to render.
> A common problem is that you have added a component in code but forgot to reference
> it in the markup (thus the component will never be rendered).

And a list of components from original BrowserInfoPage. I understand that it grabs those components from a super class. But how can I get rid of all that?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom browser info page:

```java
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.pages.BrowserInfoPage;

public class CustomBrowserInfoPage extends BrowserInfoPage {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Override `newBrowserInfoPage` in your `Session` class:

```java
protected WebPage newBrowserInfoPage()
{
    return new CustomBrowserInfoPage();
}
```

Then copy the `BrowserInfoPage.html` file from `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.pages` in the `wicket-core.jar` and customize it... It should be in the same folder as your `CustomBrowserInfoPage.java` file.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have to create an empty HTML file called "CustomBrowserInfoPage.html" next to your CustomBrowserInfoPage.java so Wicket takes your HTML file and not the one from the parent class.

Comment: I've done so from the beginning. I've left it blank. The error still occures

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are seeing something like:

```
Last cause: The component(s) below failed to render. Possible reasons could be that: 1) you have added a component in code but forgot to reference it in the markup (thus the component will never be rendered), 2) if your components were added in a parent container then make sure the markup for the child container includes them in <wicket:extend>.

1. [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = link]]
2. [BrowserInfoForm [Component id = postback]]
3. [Form [Component id = postback]]
4. [TextField [Component id = navigatorAppName]]
5. [TextField [Component id = navigatorAppVersion]]
6. [TextField [Component id = navigatorAppCodeName]]
7. [TextField [Component id = navigatorCookieEnabled]]
8. [TextField [Component id = navigatorJavaEnabled]]
9. [TextField [Component id = navigatorLanguage]]
10. [TextField [Component id = navigatorPlatform]]
11. [TextField [Component id = navigatorUserAgent]]
12. [TextField [Component id = screenWidth]]
13. [TextField [Component id = screenHeight]]
14. [TextField [Component id = screenColorDepth]]
15. [TextField [Component id = utcOffset]]
16. [TextField [Component id = utcDSTOffset]]
17. [TextField [Component id = browserWidth]]
18. [TextField [Component id = browserHeight]]
19. [TextField [Component id = hostname]]
```

Most of these components are in `BrowserInfoForm` and are in fact needed in order for the form to collect the info.

The "link" and "postback" components are in `BrowserInfoPage`, and thus must be in your html markup if you subclass this.

The `BrowserInfoPage` markup might vary slightly by wicket version (but likely not much).  Mine is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta wicket:id="meta" http-equiv="refresh" />
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:submitform();">
        If you see this, it means that both javascript and meta-refresh are not support by
        your browser configuration. Please click <a wicket:id="link" href="#">this link</a> to
        continue to the original destination.
        <div wicket:id="postback"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In order to do the work of collecting the client info, your markup needs to include the `<body onload="javascript:submitform();">` and the form itself which is in the "postback" section.

What you're seeing is probably the message starting "If you see this ...".  In my attempts to reproduce your issue, I've never seen this, but I suspect it may show for a moment before a refresh/redirect to the original destination.  You can likely eliminate it by using something like this for your "CustomBrowserInfoPage.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <meta wicket:id="meta" http-equiv="refresh" />
</head>
<body onload="javascript:submitform();">
<a wicket:id="link" href="#"></a>
<div wicket:id="postback"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If any of the fields from the `BrowserInfoForm` are visible it will be messier to hide them.  But I don't think they show anyway.

Be aware however, that if you do this, people who disable JavaScript will see a blank page and have no way to get to your real page.  That's the reason for the message and the "link".